# how to remove draw objects from pygame window?

Tags: python, window, pygame, reset, rect

I am creating a game using pygame and python. I have drawn a rectangle in the window which acts as a button. But i need to know how to remove the button once it is clicked. Heres my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
x = 0
y = 0

#Basic stuff:
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Some random Title")


while True:
    evc = pygame.event.get()
    for event in evc:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
screen.lock()
#draw button:
my_rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen,(205,201,201),Rect((245,40),(130,80)))
bf1 = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
bl = bf1.render("Play!!!", 1, (255, 255, 255))
screen.unlock()
#Check mouse click!!!
if my_rect.collidepoint(x,y):
   for event in evc:
       if event.type ==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
           screen.fill((255,255,255))



screen.blit(bl, (280, 70))
pygame.display.flip
pygame.display.update()
```

So yea i hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to draw everything to the screen again except for the parts you don't want in any more.

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
# set background or fill
background = pygame.image.load("/background.png")
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))    

my_btn = pygame.image.load("/button.png")
btn_rect = my_btn.get_rect()
screen.blit(my_btn, (0, 0))

for evt in pygame.event.get():

    if evt.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if btn_rect.collidepoint(pos):
            # do stuff
            # apply your background fill or image
            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            for element in elements_you_want_on_screen:
                screen.blit(element, (location))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

If you don't have an array of surfaces to blit:

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
# set background or fill
background = pygame.image.load("/background.png")
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))    

my_btn = pygame.image.load("/button.png")
btn_rect = my_btn.get_rect()
screen.blit(my_btn, (0, 0))

for evt in pygame.event.get():

    if evt.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if btn_rect.collidepoint(pos):
            # do stuff
            # apply your background fill or image
            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            screen.blit(your_image, (location))
            # ...and others if you have them
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: it doesnt work, when i change for element in elements_you_want_on_screen: to for element in player which I added after posting this: it says typeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not iterable

Comment: If you only have one `pygame.Surface` or the surfaces aren't in a arrary, just call blit on the surface. You can see my response, I updated it to show this.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should just create a blank screen for every frame and draw everything over again...

```
def draw(self):
self.screen.fill(self.color) #clear screen
self.draw(self.screen) # draw updated screen
```

if you have different classes in your code try adding that part in too:

```
self.#class#.draw(self.screen)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out but you can also just set the width and height of your rectangle to 0, and draw it again. In my opinion, is that way easier.

Answer (score 0):

u can make an array with all the objects and iterate the array to draw the objects and just delete the object from the array when u want to delete it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you don't have `screen.fill((your colour))`. If you add it into the loop, you can make the code draw the button while a variable is `True`. When you click the button, make the variable `False`. That should make the button disappear after you click it.

Hope that helps!