# Delete draw when clicking

Tags: python, pygame

I did a lot of research on how to delete a drawing on the screen after clicking it, and I couldn't do that

Try1 [how to remove draw objects from pygame window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516543/how-to-remove-draw-objects-from-pygame-window)
Try2 [How to remove a drawn circle in pygame? (without "going over" other things)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425871/how-to-remove-a-drawn-circle-in-pygame-without-going-over-other-things?noredirect=1&lq=1)

When clicked on the circle it will remove itself, and thus create another circle to be able to click.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import mixer

pygame.init()
musica = 'circles.mp3'
mixer.music.load(musica)
mixer.music.play()

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("OSU DA DEEP WEB")
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
screen.fill(WHITE)

#posição
width = 500 -30
height = 500 - 30
widthposition = random.randrange(width)
heightposition = random.randrange(width)
#sistema de pontos
points = 0

circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (400, 300), 25)

def draw():
    print('CLicked')
    circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (400, 300), 25)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
            
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: first you have to use `event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` to check if you clicked and `event.button == 0` to check if it is left button and then clear screen and draw new circle.

Comment: you don't have to run `pygame.init()` two times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check `event` to catch when left button was click and then you can draw white background and draw circle

```
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if event.button == pygame.BUTTON_LEFT:
            screen.fill(WHITE)
            draw(screen)
```

But this still doesn't check if you clicked on circle.

---

Minimal working code.

```
import sys
import random
import pygame

# --- constants ---

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500

# --- functions ---

def draw(screen):
    print('Clicked')

    x = random.randrange(30, WIDTH-30)
    y = random.randrange(30, HEIGHT-30)

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (x, y), 25)

# --- main ---

musica = 'circles.mp3'

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load(musica)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

screen.fill(WHITE)
draw(screen)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
            
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == pygame.BUTTON_LEFT:
                screen.fill(WHITE)
                draw(screen)
                
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

`draw.circle` gives object `pygame.Rect()` with rectangle area used by circle and you could use it to "check collision" with mouse position

```
 circle_rect = pygame.draw.circle(...)

 #... code ...

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == pygame.BUTTON_LEFT:
                if circle_rect.collidepoint(even.pos):
                    screen.fill(WHITE)
                    draw(screen)
```

and it check position in rectangle area so it works better but not ideal

---

```
import sys
import random
import pygame

# --- constants ---

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500

# --- functions ---

def draw(screen):
    print('Clicked')

    x = random.randrange(30, WIDTH-30)
    y = random.randrange(30, HEIGHT-30)

    circle_rect = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (x, y), 25)
    
    return circle_rect

# --- main ---

musica = 'circles.mp3'

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load(musica)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

screen.fill(WHITE)
circle_rect = draw(screen)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
            
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == pygame.BUTTON_LEFT:
                if circle_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    screen.fill(WHITE)
                    circle_rect = draw(screen)
                
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

There is function to check collicion in cicle area but it works for two `pygame.sprite.Sprite`, not for single `pygame.Rect` and mouse position (single point). You would have to convert mouse position and `pygame.Rect` to `pygame.sprite.Sprite` but it is to complex for this problem.

Doc: [pygame.sprite.collide_circle()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle)

OR you can use [pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to) to calculate distance between mouse position and center of circle - it has to be equal or smaller then `25`

```
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if event.button == pygame.BUTTON_LEFT:
            pos = pygame.math.Vector2(event.pos)
            if pos.distance_to(circle_rect.center) <= 25:
                screen.fill(WHITE)
                circle_rect = draw(screen)
```

---

```
import sys
import random
import pygame

# --- constants ---

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500

# --- functions ---

def draw(screen):
    print('Clicked')

    x = random.randrange(30, WIDTH-30)
    y = random.randrange(30, HEIGHT-30)

    circle_rect = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (x, y), 25)
    
    return circle_rect

# --- main ---

musica = 'circles.mp3'

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load(musica)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

screen.fill(WHITE)
circle_rect = draw(screen)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
            
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == pygame.BUTTON_LEFT:
                pos = pygame.math.Vector2(event.pos)
                if pos.distance_to(circle_rect.center) <= 25:
                    screen.fill(WHITE)
                    circle_rect = draw(screen)
                
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you will want to add other object which will move then you will have to organize it in different way. In `while True` in every loop you will have to clear screen and draw again all object. And this needs more changes

[image]

```
import sys
import random
import pygame

# --- constants ---

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)

WIDTH  = 500
HEIGHT = 500

FPS = 25

# --- classes ---

class Circle():

    def __init__(self, x, y, r, color, random=False):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = r
        self.color = color
        
        # vector to check collision
        self.center = pygame.math.Vector2((x, y))
        
        if random:
            self.set_random_position()
        
    def draw(self, screen):
        #pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.r)   
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, self.center, self.r)   
        
    def check_collision(self, position):
        return self.center.distance_to(position) <= self.r
            
    def set_random_position(self):
        self.x = random.randint(30, WIDTH-30)   # `randint` better then `randrange`
        self.y = random.randint(30, HEIGHT-30)  # `randint` better then `randrange`

        # vector to check collision        
        self.center = pygame.math.Vector2(self.x, self.y)
                
    def move_random(self):                
        dx = random.randint(-5, 5)  # `randint` better then `randrange`
        dy = random.randint(-5, 5)  # `randint` better then `randrange`
        
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy
        
        if self.x < self.r:
            self.x = self.r
            
        if self.x > WIDTH-self.r:
            self.x = WIDTH-self.r
            
        if self.y < self.r:
            self.y = self.r
            
        if self.y > HEIGHT-self.r:
            self.y = HEIGHT-self.r
            
        self.center = pygame.math.Vector2(self.x, self.y)

    
# --- functions ---

# ... empty ...

# --- main ---

musica = 'circles.mp3'

pygame.init()
#pygame.mixer.music.load(musica)
#pygame.mixer.music.play()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

# create circle
circle = Circle(0, 0, 25, RED, random=True)

# create other objects and keep on list
others = [Circle(0, 0, 10, GREEN, random=True) for _ in range(100)]
    
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:

    # - events - (without draws)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
            
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == pygame.BUTTON_LEFT:
                if circle.check_collision(event.pos):
                    # only change `x,y` without drawing
                    circle.set_random_position()
    
    # - updates - (without draws)
    
    # move other objects from list        
    for item in others:
        item.move_random()
              
    # - draws - (without events and updates)
                      
    # clear screen                      
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # draw circle
    circle.draw(screen)
        
    # draw other objects from list        
    for item in others:
        item.draw(screen)

    # send on monitor        
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    # - FPS -
    
    # to keep the same speed on different computers (with different CPU speed)
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot, now I will only need when he clicks the circle to change the position

Comment: My code already change circle position when you click in any place on `screen`. I created code which uses `rectangle area` near `circle` to check mouse click. And I'm working on example with `circle area`.

Comment: Now it was exactly what I wanted, thanks, for helping me, and the people who come here

Comment: I added example with more objects - because these objects are moving all time so it needed different organization in code.